# Yes I usually can

Tags: meaning

In the sentence given below

> "Can you park your car near the shops?" "Yes, **I usually can**."

I don't understand the meaning of the bold part.

Comment: Note that, because modals do not have continuous forms, the question could be asking if you are able to park there on this occasion, or about whether you are able to park there in general.

Comment: Have you looked for "usually" in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

By saying "Yes, I usually can." the person says that he/she can [usually](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usually) (in mot cases, but not always) park the car near the shops.

Answer (score 0):

Usually means under normal conditions, generally, most often. (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/usually) This sentence means that normally it is possible to park near the shops, though sometimes it might not be (perhaps all the spaces are occasionally full).